# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../Read/Files.js'

Tags: javascript, electron

i'm try to import a file from other file, check the code:

#### HTML

```
<button onclick="x.method()">Click me</button>
<script src="js/Encryptor/EncryptFiles.js"></script>
```

#### JavaScript file ("EncryptFiles.js")

```
import Files from '../Read/Files.js'

class EncryptFiles extends Files {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    method() {
        console.log(this.OpenFile())
    }
}
const x = new EncryptFiles()
```

#### the other file, ("Files.js")

```
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote

export default class Files {
    OpenFile() {
        dialog.showOpenDialog({
            properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections'],
            title: 'Eliga los archivos',
            filters: [
                { name: 'Todos los archivos', extensions: ['*'] }
            ],
            showHiddenFiles: true,
        }, (files) => files)
    }
}
```

and show this error the chrome console:

[image]

Directories:

[image]

Please help me

Comment: i dont know why this doesnt uploaded the images... here the images and the same question :) https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10077#issuecomment-316880190

Comment: Can you please show me the full head section of your code in index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the below code:

```
var Files = require("../Read/Files");
```

instead of

```
import Files from '../Read/Files.js'
```

If you want to use es6 or typescript, then it should have braces (i think) (**i don't know but I read it somewhere**), so your code should be:

```
import {Files} from '../Read/Files';
```

Also keep in mind that you don't need to have extension of the file in require statement. So, your code may look like this:

import Files from '../Read/Files'

Comment: It's the default export, so no braces for future reference.

Comment: @Win Thanks for letting me know that.

Comment: @Win Also I think that we should not give it an extension if it is a js or ts file. Am I right?